# how to increase the size of the pivot in blender 2.8

Tags: modeling, animation

how to increase the size of the pivot in blender 2.8 , i need to increase the size to large[image]

Answer (score 3):

You must be talking about the gizmo. In that case, *Preferences* > *Viewport* > *Display* > *Gizmo Size*.

[image]